# Finding points where a tangent line of a vector value function intersects a surface.

Tags: vector-analysis, tangent-line

I have no idea what to do with this problem, I can't find any advise online and my book is useless. The problem involves finding points where the tangent line of a vector value function intersects with a surface. The vector valued function is $r(t)=\langle 2+t^3, 2t-2, t^2\rangle$ and the surface is $z=x^2-y.$ Any help is appreciated, have a nice day.

Comment: Do you know how to find the point where a ray, say $R(t) = (2, 3, 0) + t(4, 0, 5)$ intersects a plane, say $3x + 2y + 5z = 4$?

Comment: I don't know what that means, the only piece of info I left out was that t=0. That doesn't sound like anything related to the problem. The only problem I'm having is that I can't find the point.

Comment: I assure you it *is* related to the problem: my question was about your current level of knowledge about computing intersections. I guess, from your response, that you don't know how to compute a ray-plane intersection. Since the problem you're trying to solve is more general than that, it looks as if you need to fill in some background. In the meantime, you might want to (1) read up on ray-plane intersections, and (2) figure out how to compute a parameterization of the tangent line to a curve $r(t)$ at some particular point $r(t_0)$ of the curve.